# Search processes consuming a lot of memory

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search

I am currently monitoring the memory usage of a newly installed Sharepoint Server. Since the server is new it only has 5 active users and 2 libraries with 5 documents.

The server has only Sharepoint running on it and is configured with 8 gb RAM. 83% of the RAM is used and mainly because of the Sharepoint Search component:

[image: Sharepoint search]

Is this normal behaviour or can tune some settings to resolve this?

Comment: 8 GB is way below the minimum for a standalone SharePoint server in production. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx After you "solve" this issue you will face many more until you add RAM and resources.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott thanks! Upgraded the machine to 16gb. Runs a lot better.

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some information about this behaviour. See [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20413.sharepoint-2013-performance-issues-with-search-service-application-on-a-development-vm.aspx) and [here](http://platinumdogs.me/2014/01/07/controlling-search-noderunner-memory-usage-in-sharepoint-2013/).

You can change e.G. the Performance Levels for your crawls.

**Powershell Cmdlet:**

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService –PerformanceLevel "PartlyReduced"
```

For the setting to take effect do an `IISReset` or restart the Search Service in Central Admin

**Performance Level Explained:**

**Reduced:**

> Total number of threads = number of processors, Max Threads/host =
>   number of processors

**PartlyReduced:**

> Total number of threads = 4 times the number of processors , Max
>   Threads/host = 16 times the number of processors

**Maximum:**

> Total number of threads = 4 times the number of processors , Max
>   Threads/host = 16 times the number of processors (threads are created
>   at HIGH priority)

**Change noderunner.exe:**

You can also edit the `noderunner.exe` config file located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Search\Runtime\1.0\noderunner.exe
```

And set a value for `<nodeRunnerSettings memoryLimitMegabytes="0" />`

The zero means "unlimited" here. The only thing to do is to set to the amount of RAM you'd like to set as a limit for each `noderunner.exe` processes.

**NOTE:** Be aware, these settings might make your crawling processes slower.

Hope this will help a little.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the search service consuming a lot of memory is expected out of the box if none of these settings have been changed.

Answer (score 4):

8 GB is way below the minimum for a standalone SharePoint server in production.

See this [Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx).

After you "solve" this issue you will face many more until you add RAM and resources.